# How to set height to ExtJs Grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have follow structure:

```
TabPanel->FormPanel->Grid
```

[image]

And i want to set grid's height to all free space on formpanle. If i says `layout:`fit` in FormPanle first textfield get all space of formpanel. How to do what i want?

FormPanel:

```
var search = new Ext.FormPanel({
                labelAlign: 'top',
                frame:true,
                title: 'Поиск',
                //layout:'fit',
                viewConfig:{ forceFit: true },
                //bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
```

GridPanel:

```
var searchTab = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: searchStore,
    region: 'center',
    cm: searchCm, 
    layout:'fit',
    selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel(),
    stripeRows : true,
    height: 390,
    autoExpandColumn:'expColumn',
    loadMask: true,
    id: 'searchTab',
    title:'Найденные объекты',
    autoScroll: true,
```

Answer (score -1):

User borderLayout and devide in 2 Region.North and center. Add your top panel content in north region and grid in center region.

```
layout: 'border',
        items: [{
            title: 'North Region is resizable',
            region: 'north',     // position for region
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 100
        },{
            title: 'Center Region',
            region: 'center',     // center region is required, no width/height specified
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: {
                new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store: searchStore,
                    region: 'center',
                    cm: searchCm, 
                    layout:'fit',
                    selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel(),
                    stripeRows : true,
                    height: 390,
                    autoExpandColumn:'expColumn',
                    loadMask: true,
                    id: 'searchTab',
                    title:'????????? ???????',
                    autoScroll: true
                })
            }
        }]
```

Comment: This isn't a good answer. There is no need to nest the grid inside a panel. Also, a border layout is overkill, this is easily achieved using an hbox layout.

Comment: That should be vbox, not hbox.

Answer (score -3):

Fix the height for textfield and Try height:'100%' for gridpanel. Sushant Jain's solution is good but in that too go for height:'100%' if you want grid to occupy leftover area. region: 'center' helps to occupy leftover area by north region but if you fix height or width than even if center region expand to occupy left over area grid panel will remain on fixed height.

Comment: height: '100%' is invalid. -1.